# Problem in plotting a graph in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed in my laptop along with Windows 10 home.

Recently I reinstalled `sage` in my Ubuntu. Unfortunately whenever I am plotting a graph using the command (given below) which used to run fine before

```
G=Graph({1:[2],3:[4]})

plot(G)
```

I am getting the error

```
Cannot import scimath
```

I have also updated Ubuntu recently. What should I do now?

Comment: You say 16.04 in the text but the tag says 14.04.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the python-numpy (or python3-nympy) package. Run

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

and try again.

Comment: Hey! It worked thank you so very much;You made my day;I really had a tough time